STM32L432KC Timer interrupt only triggers once
I am trying to send a message through UART based on Timer 6 interrupt on STM32L432KC microprocessor. The prescaler is set to 39999 and the auto reload is set to 19999 to get an interrupt every 10 seconds. When i upload the code, I get the first interrupt 10 seconds in but it never triggers again. I changed timers to see if Timer 6 was clashing with something that I am already using.
I have found that when the Timer 6 counter hits ARR for the first time and interrupt triggers, The TIM6->SR stays 0 but when counter hits ARR for the second time, TIM6->SR turns 1 and interrupt does not trigger which the reference manual says its the flag UIF (Update Interrupt Pending). I was thinking maybe its a hardware issue so tried changing the timers but same story.
In the same code I am also doing ADC DMA conversions using Timer 1 interrupt which is set to trigger at 100Hz. That works without issues. The callback function is the same for all Timer interrupts so I am not sure if that has an effect on my problem.
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2024 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
// C Includes
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// 3rd-Party Includes
#include <note.h>

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */
#define NOTE_I2C_BUFFER_SIZE 0xFF
#define NOTE_PRODUCT_UID "com.dclimate.kadir.efecik:notecardtest"
/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
#define ADC_SAMPLE_BUFFER_SIZE 1000
#define ADC_RAW_TO_VOLTAGE 0.0008058608f
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_adc1;

I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim1;
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim6;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

float adcData[ADC_SAMPLE_BUFFER_SIZE];
uint16_t adcTempData;
uint16_t indexCounter = 0;


// Necessary for Notecard I/O functionality
static uint8_t serialInterruptBuffer[1];
static volatile size_t serialFillIndex = 0;
static volatile size_t serialDrainIndex = 0;
static uint32_t serialOverruns = 0;
static char serialBuffer[512];
static bool uart1Initialized = false;

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM6_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

// Note Serial Interface
bool noteSerialReset(void);
void noteSerialTransmit(uint8_t *text, size_t len, bool flush);
bool noteSerialAvailable(void);
char noteSerialReceive(void);
size_t noteDebugSerialOutput(const char *message);

// Serial Debug
size_t noteDebugSerialOutput(const char *message);


/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef *hadc) {


    adcData[indexCounter] = (ADC_RAW_TO_VOLTAGE * adcTempData) * 3 + 6;

    indexCounter++;

    if (indexCounter >= ADC_SAMPLE_BUFFER_SIZE) {
        indexCounter = 0;
    }


}
/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  MX_TIM1_Init();
  MX_TIM6_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start(&hadc1, ADC_SINGLE_ENDED);

  HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1,(uint32_t *) &adcTempData, 1);

  HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim1);
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim6);

  // Set Notecard System Interface
  NoteSetFn(malloc, free, HAL_Delay, HAL_GetTick);

  // Set Notecard Serial Interface
  NoteSetFnSerial(noteSerialReset, noteSerialTransmit, noteSerialAvailable, noteSerialReceive);

  // Configure device with ProductUID
  J *req = NoteNewRequest("hub.set");
  JAddStringToObject(req, "product", NOTE_PRODUCT_UID);
  JAddStringToObject(req, "mode", "continuous");
  NoteRequest(req);


  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      HAL_Delay(100);
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  if (HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure LSE Drive Capability
  */
  HAL_PWR_EnableBkUpAccess();
  __HAL_RCC_LSEDRIVE_CONFIG(RCC_LSEDRIVE_LOW);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSE|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.LSEState = RCC_LSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIState = RCC_MSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSICalibrationValue = 0;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIClockRange = RCC_MSIRANGE_6;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 40;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV7;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = RCC_PLLQ_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = RCC_PLLR_DIV2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Enable MSI Auto calibration
  */
  HAL_RCCEx_EnableMSIPLLMode();
}

/**
  * @brief ADC1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 0 */

  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 1 */

  /** Common config
  */
  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_ASYNC_DIV2;
  hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
  hadc1.Init.LowPowerAutoWait = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_EXTERNALTRIG_T1_TRGO;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_RISING;
  hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.Overrun = ADC_OVR_DATA_PRESERVED;
  hadc1.Init.OversamplingMode = DISABLE;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure Regular Channel
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_6;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_247CYCLES_5;
  sConfig.SingleDiff = ADC_SINGLE_ENDED;
  sConfig.OffsetNumber = ADC_OFFSET_NONE;
  sConfig.Offset = 0;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief I2C1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 1 */
  hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
  hi2c1.Init.Timing = 0x10909CEC;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2Masks = I2C_OA2_NOMASK;
  hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure Analogue filter
  */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigAnalogFilter(&hi2c1, I2C_ANALOGFILTER_ENABLE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure Digital filter
  */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigDigitalFilter(&hi2c1, 0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief TIM1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 0 */

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 1 */
  htim1.Instance = TIM1;
  htim1.Init.Prescaler = 3200-1;
  htim1.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim1.Init.Period = 100-1;
  htim1.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim1.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim1.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim1, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_UPDATE;
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger2 = TIM_TRGO2_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim1, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief TIM6 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM6_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM6_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM6_Init 0 */

  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM6_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM6_Init 1 */
  htim6.Instance = TIM6;
  htim6.Init.Prescaler = 40000-1;
  htim6.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim6.Init.Period = 20000-1;
  htim6.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim6) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim6, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM6_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM6_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief USART1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 0 */
  // Gaurantee idempotence
  if (uart1Initialized) { return; }
  uart1Initialized = true;

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 1 */
  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 2 */

  // Reset our buffer management
  serialFillIndex = serialDrainIndex = serialOverruns = 0;

  // Start the inbound receive
  HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, serialInterruptBuffer, sizeof(serialInterruptBuffer));

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief USART2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
static void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{

  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA1_Channel1_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn);

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_1 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_1 */

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD3_GPIO_Port, LD3_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : LD3_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LD3_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(LD3_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

size_t noteDebugSerialOutput(const char *message) {
  static const size_t USART2_TIMEOUT = 250;
  size_t result = 0;

  HAL_StatusTypeDef status = HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *)message, strlen(message), USART2_TIMEOUT);
  if (HAL_OK == status) {
        result = sizeof(message);
  } else {
    result = 0;
  }

  return result;
}

void noteSerial_UART_IRQHandler(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart) {
  // See if the transfer is completed
  if (huart->RxXferCount == 0) {
    if (serialFillIndex < sizeof(serialBuffer)) {
      if (serialFillIndex+1 == serialDrainIndex) {
        ++serialOverruns;
      } else {
        serialBuffer[serialFillIndex++] = serialInterruptBuffer[0];
      }
    } else {
      if (serialDrainIndex == 1) {
        ++serialOverruns;
      } else {
        serialBuffer[0] = serialInterruptBuffer[0];
        serialFillIndex = 1;
      }
    }
  }

  // Start another receive
  HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, (uint8_t *) &serialInterruptBuffer, sizeof(serialInterruptBuffer));
}

void MX_USART1_UART_DeInit(void) {
  if (!uart1Initialized) { return; }
  uart1Initialized = false;
  HAL_UART_DeInit(&huart1);
}

bool noteSerialReset() {
  MX_USART1_UART_DeInit();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  return true;
}

void noteSerialTransmit(uint8_t *text, size_t len, bool flush) {
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, text, len, 5000);
}

bool noteSerialAvailable() {
  return (serialFillIndex != serialDrainIndex);
}

char noteSerialReceive() {
  char data;
  while (!noteSerialAvailable());
  if (serialDrainIndex < sizeof(serialBuffer)) {
    data = serialBuffer[serialDrainIndex++];
  } else {
    data = serialBuffer[0];
    serialDrainIndex = 1;
  }
  return data;
}

void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{

  // If its triggered by timer 7 which should be every 10 secs
    if (htim == &htim6){
    J *req = NoteNewRequest("note.add");
    if (req != NULL) {
      JAddStringToObject(req, "file", "sensors.qo");
      JAddBoolToObject(req, "sync", true);
      J *body = JCreateObject();
      if (body != NULL) {
        if (indexCounter==0){
          JAddNumberToObject(body, "voltage", adcData[ADC_SAMPLE_BUFFER_SIZE-1]);
        }
        else {
          JAddNumberToObject(body, "voltage", adcData[indexCounter-1]);
        }
        JAddItemToObject(req, "body", body);
      }
      NoteRequest(req);
    }
  }

}

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */


Use budegger to gather more information. Just add breakpoint to timer Callback and step your code to see if your program leave callback function. Let program run, wait if brakpoints trigger again. If not, pause program and look into TIM6 registers to see if it is running, if its interrupt is enabled, if overflow flag is set.

I kept pausing during debugging to check where it was and it would end up in a HAL delay which I assumed was from the HAL_delay function in the main infinite loop but apparently NoteRequest never exits waiting the UART to time out so it gets stuck in the very first timer interrupt.
